I tried to register agent to connect with private network but not working [DBUS-CONNMAN-DART]
static Future<void> RegisterAgent(DBusObjectPath path) async {
    var introspectable = OrgFreedesktopDBusIntrospectable(dbus, 'net.connman', DBusObjectPath('/'));
    try {
      await introspectable.callRegisterAgent(path);  
      //print(x);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error in registering agent");
    }
  }

which calls
Future<void> callRegisterAgent(DBusObjectPath path, {bool noAutoStart = false, bool allowInteractiveAuthorization = true}) async {
    await callMethod('net.connman.Manager', 'RegisterAgent', [path], replySignature: DBusSignature('o'), noAutoStart: noAutoStart, allowInteractiveAuthorization: allowInteractiveAuthorization);
  }

Now I know to register agent, if there aren't any passphrase associated with the service, I need to use requestInput from net.connman.agent. But there is no indication showing that requestInput is being called.
This callregisteragent network manager is from net.connman.manager. I was able to connect with devices that was once already connected. I used Dart dbus.

I tried calling request input in using dbus, eg await callMethod('net.connman.Agent', 'RequestInput', [{some map containing ssid and passphrase}], replySignature: DBusSignature('o'), noAutoStart: noAutoStart, allowInteractiveAuthorization: allowInteractiveAuthorization);

Tried using network manager, but quite complicated. There were problems like I could generate dart file from xml of network.connman.device but it had quite no of errors. So i couldn't access or read any of properties

There were this package that uses network manager, NM that was made before two years, They have their own example codes [wifi.dart], which wasn't working.

I tried mixing both my approach and nm package, the only problem it had is in the line object.requestScan()
I tried using if(lastscan) and it returned -1.

Request scan need access points which when i tried printing using dbus-send, returned empty array as there were no access points but there were one when i tried using connman services, depicting A*.


